# App to give to the sales rep as catalog, supporting local videos?

Tags: android, catalog

We are looking for an Android app that we can give to our salespeople as a catalog of our products. Basically, it should allow to configure a list of products and associate photos and/or videos to each one (from the phone/tablet local storage).
We tried using [Adiante](https://www.adianteapps.com) and liked it a lot, but it cannot play local videos :( Only YouTube ones.
The app doesn't have to be free.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? What OS should it run on? What price are you willing to pay, or must it come for free?

Comment: Hi! As stated the OS should be Android, I'll add more details though

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, reopened! Apologies for my missing the OS – but without the details you just added it had been hard to answer anyway :) // Cleaning up comments now. Good luck! // Oh, PS: Would a [point-of-sales app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_1074) fit your needs?

Comment: I'll have a look at your list, thanks :) The "hard" part is the video support...